# How do I get the value the user choose from the dynamic table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a dynamic table and I want to click on the link example location A and go to another php page.
And however, in the another php page, I want to select some details from location A. May I know how do I get the values? I tried some ways but it still fails.

Creating dynamic table:

```
<?php
            include "mysqli.connect.php";
            // Make a MySQL Connection

            $_session['place'] = $row['links'];

            $retrieveLocation = "SELECT COUNT(c.userid) AS userid, p.places, p.address, p.telephone, p.links FROM promotion AS p LEFT JOIN candy AS c on p.places = c.places GROUP BY p.places ORDER BY userid desc"; 

            $result = $mysqli->query($retrieveLocation);    
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {   
            echo "<tr><td>{$row['places']}</td><td>{$row['address']}</td><td>{$row['telephone']}</td><td>{$row['userid']}</td><td><a href=\"".$row['links']."\">View</a></td></tr>";
            }

        ?>
```

So it will generate the values from the database and output as table:

```
places | address | telephone | userid | links
----------------------------------------------
A                                     | A.php
B                                     | B.php
C                                     | C.php
D                                     | D.php
```

A.php

```
<?php
                include "mysqli.connect.php";

                // Make a MySQL Connection      
                $retrieve = "SELECT username, product, rating FROM ratings WHERE places='".$_SESSION['place']."'"; 

                $result = $mysqli->query($retrieve);    
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {   
                    echo "<tr><td>{$row['product']}</td><td>{$row['rating']}</td><td>{$row['username']}</td></tr>";
                }
            ?>
```

So for my last column, when user click, it will direct them to the page(example A.php). And get into A.php page, I need to select some details from location A and display it out. 
Can please help? Thanks. (the session part i've tried just now, it didnt work)

Answer (score 0):

In the URI ponting to the new page you should include an additional parameter with the id of the selected item.

I mean, something like that:

```
"<a href=\"showItem.php?propertyId={$row['id']}\">View property</a>"
```